# Name dosent exist in Current Context Error

Tags: c#, winforms

```
 public Dictionary<string, TextBox> name_tbs = new Dictionary<string, TextBox>();
    TextBox TextBoxbyName(string tb_name)
    {
        return name_tbs(tb_name);
    }
```

Now it shows the error name_tbs dosent exist in current context .

Comment: Mmmm... use square brackets? `name_tbs[tb_name]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to place it inside the [], because you are accessing using the key of a dictionary,

```
Dictionary<string, TextBox> name_tbs = new Dictionary<string, TextBox>();     
TextBox TextBoxbyName(string tb_name)
{           
  return name_tbs[tb_name];
}
```